# Unable to pass parameter from an xhtml/jsf file to client applet

Tags: spring, spring-security, applet

I am trying to pass a parameter value from an xhtml file to an embedded applet in the standard form. It looks something like this:
(XHTML file)

```
<APPLET CODE="AppletParameterTest.class" WIDTH="400" HEIGHT="50">
  <PARAM NAME="font"    VALUE="Dialog">
  <PARAM NAME="size"    VALUE="24">
  <PARAM NAME="string"  VALUE="Hello, world ... it's me.   :)">
</APPLET>
```

(Applet code)

```
public class AppletParameterTest extends Applet {

 public void paint(Graphics g) {

  String myFont   = getParameter("font");
  String myString = getParameter("string");
```

If I use a normal html file and try the same, I am able to do this without a fuss.

But my development scenario involves JSF, Spring and Spring Security and I am not sure if it's causing the trouble. The parameters are not received at the applet. But on a different application where I am not using spring security, the parameter passing works fine.

Spring security configuration file is aptly configured to ensure authenticated access to the particular folder where the applet and xhtml resides:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Can you suggest, why its happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: How does the generated html look client-side? If it contains all param tags , it is 100% not JSF related

Comment: Actually the parameters are being passed to an applet. Its in the applet where the parameter values are null.

Comment: So then it is certainly not jsf related

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. The issue was because of the use of 'verbatim' tag. It seems when spring security is used with JSF, 'verbatim' tag doesn't allow passing the parameter to the applet.